# How does buffering for TCP packets work?

Tags: networking, kernel, tcp, socket, buffer

If I write a few times in a quick succession on a socket (with the POSIX function `write`), usually all the data I wrote gets sent in a single TCP packets. Unless I write too much or unless I wait too long between the writes.

Is the kernel buffering the data I write on a socket and sending packets out at regular intervals? Or does the libc handle this? How long does the kernel wait before sending a packet? Can I request to send a mostly empty packet immediately? Is UDP or other protocols handled differently?

I'm curious to understand how all of this work, but I struggled at finding information on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OS likely does some short term buffering before sending. E.g. the Linux man page [`tcp(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) mentions the `TCP_NODELAY` option to disable that (see also [`setsockopt(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html)):

> `TCP_NODELAY`
> If set, disable the Nagle algorithm.  This means that
> segments are always sent as soon as possible, even if
> there is only a small amount of data.  When not set, data
> is buffered until there is a sufficient amount to send
> out, thereby avoiding the frequent sending of small
> packets, which results in poor utilization of the network.
> This option is overridden by `TCP_CORK`; however, setting
> this option forces an explicit flush of pending output,
> even if `TCP_CORK` is currently set.

[Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) being the actual buffering algorithm. If I followed the breadcrumbs correctly, [RFC 1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122) appears to be the currently-valid definition for it.

It's the kernel, not libc. The C library does buffering for stdio streams (`FILE *`), but `write()` and `send()` go directly to the kernel.

With UDP, the sizes of the datagrams are significant and visible to the upper layers, so similar mangling is not possible there.

Comment: Thanks, this answers all my questions.